# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Firstly I have a pandas series of recommended product  (recmd_prdt_list). In this series there is a possibility of presence of deleted products. So as to remove deleted products from the recommended products, I did the following :

```
recmd_prdt_list = user_lookup['Recommended items']
recmd_prdt_list
```

0      PLV08, PLPD04, PBC07, 555, PLF02, 963, PLF07, ...

1      123, 345, R922, Asus009, AIMAC, Th001, SAM S9,...

2      LGRFG, LG, 1025, COFMH, 8048, BY7, PLHL4, 569,...

3      COFMH, 5454, 8048, 1025, LG, len123, Th001, PL...

4      LGRFG, AIM-Pro, 569, Asus009, PLHL3, PL04, PLH...

5      PLV08, PLF09, PLF02, PBC04, PLF07, AIM-Pro, PL...

```
type(recmd_prdt_list)
```

pandas.core.series.Series

## DataFrame of product status

```
product_status
```

```
ItemCode  Status DeletedStatus
AIMAC     2      True
AIM-Pro   2      True
SAM S9    2      True
SH MV     2      True
COFMH     2      True
LGRFG     2      True
```

```
type(product_status)
```

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

```
first_row = user_lookup['Recommended items'][0]
first_row
```

'PLV08, PLPD04, PBC07, 555, PLF02, 963, PLF07, HG8, jealous21, 4'

```
type(first_row)
```

str

#### Converting the str to list

```
first_row_list = list(first_row .split(","))
first_row_list
```

['PLV08',
 ' PLPD04',
 ' PBC07',
 ' 555',
 ' PLF02',
 ' 963',
 ' PLF07',
 ' HG8',
 ' jealous21',
 ' 4']

From the first row i took first itemcode to check the deleted status :

```
product_details = product_status.loc[product_status['ItemCode'] == 'PLV08']
product_details
```

```
ItemCode   Status   DeletedStatus  

PLV08       2            False
```

```
type(product_details)
```

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

```
product_details['DeletedStatus']
```

693    False

Name: DeletedStatus, dtype: bool

So as to check the deleted status of each product in the respective row and save to a new list. I wrote the following code :

```
itemcode = 'PLV08'
activ_product = []
if itemcode in product_status['ItemCode'].values:
    print(itemcode)
    product_details = product_status.loc[product_status['ItemCode'] == itemcode]
    print(product_details)
    if product_details['Status'] == 2 & product_details['DeletedStatus'] == 'False':
        activ_product.append(itemcode)
```

Error :

```
PLV08
     ClientId ItemCode  Status  DeletedStatus
499      2213    PLV08       2          False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-9507e1ada5f7> in <module>()
      5     product_details = product_status.loc[product_status['ItemCode'] == itemcode]
      6     print(product_details)
----> 7     if product_details['Status'] == 2 & product_details['DeletedStatus'] == 'False':
      8         activ_product.append(itemcode)

~/.virtualenvs/sysg_python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    951         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    952                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 953                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    954 
    955     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How to get solve of this error?

Comment: This error always irritates me because it can appear in some pretty random places, but in this case you probably just need to wrap the two conditionals in brackets:`if (product_details['Status'] == 2) & (product_details['DeletedStatus'] == False):` - note that there should not generally be quotation marks around the word `False`, since that changes the meaning from a boolean field that's True/False to a string field that's literally the word "False".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, to make logical test in Python, you should not use `&` for a single values equalities (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488928/where-are-the-ampersand-and-vertical-bar-characters-used-in-python/6490106#6490106)) and you should not use question marks around boolean values `False` and `True`.

Now, concerning you specific error : When writing `product_details['Status']` and `product_details['DeletedStatus']` you get each time a `Series`, which you cannot test for a logical `and` between them. If you have unique item codes, you can use:

```
if product_details.iloc[0]['Status'] == 2 and product_details.iloc[0]['DeletedStatus'] == False:
    activ_product.append(itemcode)
```

It will simply select the first row of `product_details` and subset the desired column so that the result is a single value and you can compare it.

Comment: the error solved but got another problem. Above I specified one itemcode directly. For checking the condition for all itemcode in first_row_list I put a for loop. So the code will be :
`activ_product = []`
`for item in first_row_list:`
    `if item in product_status['ItemCode'].values:`
        `product_details = product_status.loc[product_status['ItemCode'] == item]`
        `if product_details.iloc[0]['Status'] == 2 and product_details.iloc[0]['DeletedStatus'] == False:`
            `activ_product.append(item)`
After running this the activ_product contains only first itemcode.

Comment: have you checked the values you have in `first_row_list`?

Comment: yes, I checked. the first_row_list have 3 values which satisfy the condition.